# Azure MSAL Integration not work when install generated signed apk with keystore or app download from play store

Tags: flutter, azure, azure-active-directory, google-play-console

I have created mobile app with Azure MSAL integration and use production redirect uri also. mobile app work properly with release apk. but when I uploaded apk to play store and after download from play store app does not work.

this is the error come from

Unhandled Exception: Error initializing client. Please ensure correctly configuration supplied

[ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtcNt.png)

I used this package [azure_ad_authentication: ^1.0.5](https://pub.dev/packages/azure_ad_authentication)

And login with MSAL with Azure portel

i tried with my pc hash key, sha1 key, play console sha key and change redirect url accordingly
but it's not work while i install generated signed release apk